# Why is Visual C++ 2010 still calling Orphan_all when a vector is destroyed with _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, release

Visual C++ newbie here.  (I came up to speed on Visual C++ 6 somewhat ages ago, and have used the IDE sporadically since then, but still don't feel comfortable with it.  Give me a good old commandline and get off my lawn, that's my attitude.)

I'm helping out on an app built with Visual C++ 2010 (it's a solution file with 20 subprojects), and noticed something odd: even though _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL and _SECURE_SCL are both defined to zero in the project's properties, adding /FAs for one of the .cpp files still shows calls to checked iterator stuff, e.g.

```
   call    DWORD PTR __imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base0@std@@QAEXXZ
```

I've verified (with printf) that both defines are zero.   Furthermore, these calls seem very fragile; if I delete seemingly trivial amounts of code from the function involved, the calls to Orphan_all vanish.

So: why is Visual C++ 2010 still calling Orphan_all when a vector is destroyed with _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0 ?
(Also, I've also heard that the cl.exe itself in windows sdk v7.1 and several games all seem to import _Orphan_all@_Container_base0@std@@QAEXXZ from msvcp100.dll, which seems odd for released products.  What should msvcp100.dll's _Orphan_all@_Container_base0@std@@QAEXXZ do -- is it a no-op, or does it actually do things, like the one in msvcp100d.dll?)

Comment: What are your compiler flags? In particular, are you compiling debug?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT.**

So, since _Vector_val is inherited from  _Container_base

```
#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 0
typedef _Container_base0 _Container_base;
typedef _Iterator_base0 _Iterator_base;

 #else /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 0 */
typedef _Container_base12 _Container_base;
typedef _Iterator_base12 _Iterator_base;
 #endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 0 */
```

where _Container_base0 is

```
        // CLASSES _Container_base*, _Iterator_base*
struct _CRTIMP2_PURE _Container_base0
    {   // base of all containers
    void _Orphan_all()
        {   // orphan all iterators
        }

    void _Swap_all(_Container_base0&)
        {   // swap all iterators
        }
    };
```

You use empty _Orphan_all when _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL is 0.

Comment: This is with compiler options /MD /EHsc /D_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0 /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /O2, among others.  Without /O2, there are a whole lot of calls.  With /O2, just a couple.  So I guess it's a case of the optimizer missing a few bets.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the function is selected through SFINAE (rather than *#ifdef*-ed out of the library), in which case there could be an empty `_Orphan_all` function. If you compile in debug mode, the function will still be there, once you bump the optimizer up, it should be able to remove the call.

Note that I don't have a windows box to check what the implementation of the standard library in visual studio looks like, so this is just a random guess looking at my crystal ball.